# Wiener Process Textbook or Reference Specifically Containing Ramp Intersection (or Exit Time) Analysis

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales, stopping-times

I am looking for a reference (preferably a textbook so that additional preparation material is handy) that calculates the exit time of a Wiener process from a region bounded by sloped lines.
Thank you,
Gary